# Cant get more than one element's attr in app.get Node.js

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js

```
     var SomeObject = xmlDoc2.get('Objects').childNodes();

 SomeObject.forEach(function (child) {

     var theId = child.attr('id');


     if (theId !== null) {
         var theIdVal = theId.value();
         console.log('Id: ' + theIdVal);

         app.get('/obj/:id', function (req, res) {
             if (req.params.id == theIdVal) {

                     res.json('This is id: ' + theIdVal);
                     console.log('This is id: ' + theIdVal)

             }
             else {

             }
         })

     }
 });
```

The problem is that I cen only get /obj/first    --> first element's id url. 
If I type "Two"  itg just keep loading the page, without a result. ( and lets say xml looks like this:)

```
<Objects>
<Object id="First">
</Object>
<Object id="Two">
</Object>

<Object id="Three">
</Object>
</Objects>
```

Comment: Isn't `childNodes()` returning a NodeList? Maybe just try a plain old `for` loop instead.

Comment: You should not use `Object` as a variable name.

Comment: I have different name, just didnt want to show it here - my bad I used "object" here to just show it

Comment: Sirko. but how should I literate in xml using "for" ?

Comment: ??Anybody? could help?